# hosting server compiles .aspx but not .cshtml

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, web-applications, web-hosting, web-deployment

I have been looking in internet for a good answer for this for a week now, but couldn't find any answer for it. I will give all the information I have and I think might be helpful for you guys to solve this frustrating issue and finally I will tell you the problem it self and the tests that I have done and their results.

I'm using ASP.NET MVC 3 (C#) and this is what I did step by step:

1. I have added the .dll and .xml files to my project and changed the Copy Local to True according to many online websites and tutorial.
2. I have built my project and published it locally on my own computer (by using File System publish method).
3. Then I have implemented the deployed website into my hosting server by FileZilla software.

This is my Bin folder after deployment in my website:

- EntityFramework.dll
- Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure.dll
- PagedList.dll
- System.Web.Abstraction.dll
- System.Web.Helpers.dll
- System.Web.Mvc.dll
- System.Web.Providers.dll
- System.Web.Razor.dll
- System.Web.Routing.dll
- System.Web.WebPages.Deployment.dll
- System.Web.WebPages.dll
- System.Web.WebPages.Razor.dll

This is my packages.config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="EntityFramework" version="5.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="jQuery" version="1.7.1.1" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="jQuery.UI.Combined" version="1.8.20.1" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="jQuery.Validation" version="1.9.0.1" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc" version="3.0.20105.1" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Providers.Core" version="1.1" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Providers.LocalDB" version="1.1" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Razor" version="1.0.20105.408" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages" version="1.0.20105.408" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure" version="1.0.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Modernizr" version="2.5.3" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="PagedList" version="1.15.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
</packages>
```

My hosting server DOES support MVC and ASP.NET 4.0 and the server is IIS7.0 (Integrated pipeline). However, the latest ASP.NET framework that they support is 4.0. In my project's properties it shows that the target framework is 4.5, but when I deployed the website, inside its properties it shows that the target framework is 4.0.

## The problem

When I open my website on Internet, it manages to find the Index.cshtml file in the directory, but however, only the plain html and css can be compiled, the server can't compile the C# codes for some reasons that is unknown to me. That is why all my links are null and empty references because `<a href="@Url.Action("Learn", "Home")">` is what I used for linking pages.

But anyhow, when I used a simple .aspx file (which I'm not very familiar with) which used Visual Basic language, it was able to compile the file perfectly without any problem.

What could possibly be the problem? I have had a long discussion with my hosting service provider customer service (godaddy.com) and even though they passed my case to their "most advanced technicians" but still they couldn't find the problem.

Could this issue be from a library that I am missing in my bin folder?

I have to say this as well that my website works perfectly when I run it under IIS 7.0 Express on my own computer localhost server.

Thanks and regards,
Amin

Comment: You need to target the `.NET 4.0 Framework` if that's what your server supports.  The reason it works locally is because you have `.NET Framework 4.5` installed

Comment: I see, but then why does it show the target frame is 4.0 on my website (the deployed version)?

Comment: Also, is there any tutorials you would suggest for me to downgrade the .NET Framework for an already built project? That would be really great :)

Comment: Have you installed MVC or tried to publish in a way pushing deployment dependency dlls(with VS 2010 SP1)?

Comment: The server, has MVC installed on it. But still yes I did add the required dlls, but I'm using VS 2012 Web Express.

Comment: .NET Framework 4.5 is an inplace replacement for .NET Framework tno need for me to post your research material for you since there is nothing you need to do to migrate backwards unless your using .NET 4.5 only classes.

Comment: That was exactly my reaction when I saw my C# codes are not getting compiled. There is no error message, because the C# codes are not being compiled. I have contact them many times through email, they told me they have passed my case to their professional technicians but it has been a week not that they have not replied for any results.

Comment: My C# codes are just simply being ignored by the compiler. I have tested the C# codes in .aspx as well, but still it doesn't compiled the codes. However, VB codes can be compiled easily.